# Adding the values of two pointers and saving the addition into another pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm a beginner but what I'm trying to do is getting the value of two pointers and saving the 'action' of their addition. I thought pointer to function would work  but can't find how to initialize a pointer to a function with it's parameters. Something like this.

```
int foo(int *a, int *b){return *a + *b;}
//main

int *a = new int, *b = new int;
*a = 10;
*b = 20;
int (*ab)(int *a, int *b) = foo(a, b); // here I try to save it like it is but I can't.
                                       // otherwise It would be like calling a function to get the result,
                                       // my idea was to save it to a variable.    
std::cout << ab << std::endl;

*a = 2000;
  
std::cout << ab << std::endl; // so the 'value' of ab would change here.
```

I was trying to think this to avoid having to change values that depend on one another. Maybe there's an easier way but I haven't got to it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a pointer depend on the values of *multiple* other pointers the way you want. But you could write a lambda that captures the dependent variables by reference, and returns the value returned by the call to `foo`. Any changes to the values pointed at by the pointers will be reflected in what the lambda returns. You'll need to use call syntax to access the value.

```
auto ab = [&] { return foo(a,b); };  // define ab

std::cout << ab() << std::endl;      // use ab
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xE1hr9q76).